# How do I avoid two logins for my players Google Account and Paypal Account?

Tags: braintree, google-account

I'm doing the casual game revenue model of payments for virtual currency.  My players right now can login with a google account.   I don't know a way to avoid a second login to Paypal/Braintree or some other payment system. Google Wallet doesn't seem to be the answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

At some point you need to store a mapping between their Google authenticated user and a Braintree customer id in your database (or other long-term storage). This way you can look up a Braintree customer id based on the authentication session in Google.

When you generate the Braintree client token [for use in the Drop-in](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/#present-drop-in-ui), simply [include the customer id in your token generate call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/#specify-a-customer-id). The app will be able to look up previously used payment methods based on this client token.

Comment: Great. Hopefully I can get to this, this week.